# Please help me in figuring out What does this command do?

Tags: sed, pam

I saw a command to fix issues while running cron jobs on stackoverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926465/issues-running-cron-in-docker-on-different-hosts
I am ntsure what exactly this command does since I am new to unix commands. Can any noble soul spell out what each part does ?

`sed --regexp-extended --in-place 's/^session\s+required\s+pam_loginuid.so$/session optional pam_loginuid.so/' /etc/pam.d/crond`

Comment: Before we start, do you know anything at all about `sed`? Have you read `man sed`?

Comment: What's the problem you're actually trying to solve? This is an incomplete command line (it ends with `&&` which is a _logical and_ with a continuation to another command)

Comment: Would be good also if you share the link to the original answer on stackoverflow, so we can get some background information.

Comment: Added the details of the original answer i found on stackoverflow. It would be nice if you folks removed the downvotes you did ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is a command-line text editor, used like `sed -flags command file`, which is most commonly used for doing find-and-replace with regular expressions. It can do a lot, I find https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html to be a good beginner-ish guide (friendlier than the `man` page)

Regular expressions (regex) are a bit like a complicated system of wildcards, that lets you look for patterns of text rather than specific things

`--regexp-extended` tells it to use extended regular expressions, which have more features

`--in-place` tells it to change the file, rather than printing the output to the shell or stdout

`'s/foo/bar'` is the substitute command for sed (s stands for substitute), which finds the first 'foo' on every line and swaps it for 'bar'

`^session`: the `^` means the start of a line in regex

`\s+`: `\s` means "any whitespace", so space or tab or similar, in regex; `+` means one or more, so this matches one or more spaces/tabs/etc. `+` needs extended regex

`...nuid.so$`: the `$` means the end of a line in regex

So, this is finding every line that's like `session optional pam_loginuid.so` but with more spaces/tabs, and replacing it with `session optional pam_loginuid.so` with one space, and with `required` replaced with `optional`, in the file `/etc/pam.d/crond`

The `&&` means "run the next command if this one returns zero", and most things in bash return zero if they don't crash. sed returns zero even if it doesn't find anything to substitute, so this will almost always happen

The `\` at the end makes it ignore the newline, so the command on the next line gets executed too, unless something doesn't work

So basically it's changing `required` to `optional` and removing extra spaces, but hopefully this helps you figure out what `sed 's/thing/otherThing/'` does in general